# Where should I place resources.resx in a ASP.NET web application?

Tags: asp.net, embedded-resource

I'm a newbie with ASP.NET web applications. When I create an ASP.NET web app project, there's a file called resources.resx in the folder My Project. Working in my computer I can access this file and its content without any problem. But when I deploy the application I can't access this file. I've tried copying the file seperately, and the folder (My Project) seperately, with the file in it, but no luck. Is there a way to achieve this?

PS: I've read something about implicit localization and explicit localization but I'd like to know if it can be done this way.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to view it in production?

Comment: Actually not viewing it. Only accessing but maybe changing it if it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's embedded into your DLL when you build (compile). So you can't change it when it's deployed.

If you want to see it in your DLL, you'll have to use a tool like [Reflector](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), etc.

You can read more on resources [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), starting from the 'Compiling Resources into Assemblies' title (as you know how to use them by now).

Comment: Thanks Peter. I'll keep investigating. I suppose I'll use global or local resource files.

Answer (score 1):

Well my suggestion is to use global and local resources.
In production you'll have resx file stored in:

- App_GlobalResources: available in all application
- App_LocalResources: one for each folder you want resources.

They are XML files visibile and editable.

I use it to allow me to modify string localization resources without recompiling and deploying.
And you can also give a web interface to the end user to allow him to self translate and localize strings at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer too. How could I mark your answer as correct too? Only one is let to be marked?

Comment: Yes you can vote as answer only one, the one you think is the best (you can change it at any time if you change your mind).
In addition you can always vote up how many answers you think are valid.
And last you can vote also comments.
Check out [Stackoverflow faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)